# Binding uicomponent in onclick attribute

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I would like to toggle the styleClass of an uicomponent when an user clicks on it via javascript. However both buttons below can't be of the class "active" at the same time. I'd use the id directly in the function but that's not possible because the buttons are inside `ui:repeat` tags. I know forms inside `ui:repeat` is not advised but I've made it before being aware of that fact and that shouldn't be an issue for what I'm asking. So instead of using the id's I tried to use the `binding` attribute but that doesn't seem to work (I don't know if that's even legal to do).

```
<ui:repeat var="thread" value="#{categoryBean.category.thethreads}">
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-chevron-up"
        binding="#{upvoteBtn}"
        action="#{threadVotesBean.upvote(thread)}" styleClass="voteBtn #{threadVotesBean.isUpvoteActive(thread) ? 'active': 'notActive'}"
        onclick="toggleClass(#{upvoteBtn.clientId},#{upvoteBtn.clientId},'up')"/>                                       
    <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-chevron-down"
        binding="#{downvoteBtn}"
        styleClass="voteBtn" action="#{threadVotesBean.downvote(thread)}"
        onclick="toggleClass(#{upvoteBtn.clientId}, #{downvoteBtn.clientId},'down')"/>
</h:form>
</ui:repeat>

 <!-- I don't know javascript so this is a bit funky just for testing  -->

    <script>
    function toggleClass(idUp, idDown, buttonPressed){
        alert("entered");
        var classUpvote =  document.getElementById(idUp).className;
        var classDownvote = document.getElementById(idDown).className; 
        if(buttonPressed == "up"){
            alert(classUpvote);
        }
    }
</script>
```

As for why I wanna do that: I have topics that user can downvote or upvote via little arrow buttons. When those buttons are pressed the color of the button changes from blue to orange.  I would like to use javascript if possible so there is no delay for the button to switch color and I don't want to refresh the page.

Comment: Clumsy. Just make use of `this` in JavaScript.

Comment: I'm really unfamiliar with js but I've to link the two buttons so I'm not sure if this could work.

Comment: You've jQuery at hands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's dumb, I just forgot the '' and it works.  It should be :

```
onclick="toggleClass('#{upvoteBtn.clientId}', '#{downvoteBtn.clientId}','down')"/>
```

instead of

```
onclick="toggleClass(#{upvoteBtn.clientId}, #{downvoteBtn.clientId},'down')"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using primefaces? Which version?
See if you can use: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneButton.xhtml

Without primefaces and with JQuery at hands, it is easy to do:

Try this:

```html
<div id="threads">
    <ui:repeat var="thread" value="#{categoryBean.category.thethreads}">
        <h:form>
            <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-chevron-up" 
                                binding="#{upvoteBtn}" 
                                action="#{threadVotesBean.upvote(thread)}" 
                                styleClass="voteBtn #{threadVotesBean.isUpvoteActive(thread) ? 'active': ''}" />                                       
            <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-chevron-down" 
                                binding="#{downvoteBtn}" 
                                styleClass="voteBtn" 
                                action="#{threadVotesBean.downvote(thread)}" />
        </h:form>
    </ui:repeat>
</div>
```

```js
    // function called when DOM is ready (page fully loaded.)
    $(function(){

        //selecting the DIV element with id 'threads'.
        var $threads = $('div#threads');

        // The DIV element injects an event on all elements with class 'voteBtn'.
        $threads.on('click', '.voteBtn', function(event) {
            // select the element that triggered the click event
            var $clickedBtn = $(event.currentTarget);

            // lookup for parent element with 'form' tag name and find inside it all children elements with class 'voteBtn' to remove 'active' class. 
            $clickedBtn.parent('form').find('.voteBtn').removeClass('active');

            // then, back to the trigger element, just add 'active' class to it.
            $clickedBtn.addClass('active');
        });

    });
```

Or this is better:

```html
<h:form id="threadsForm">
    <ui:repeat var="thread" value="#{categoryBean.category.thethreads}">
        <div id="group">
            <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-chevron-up" binding="#{upvoteBtn}" action="#{threadVotesBean.upvote(thread)}" styleClass="voteBtn #{threadVotesBean.isUpvoteActive(thread) ? 'active': 'notActive'}" />                                       
            <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-chevron-down" binding="#{downvoteBtn}" styleClass="voteBtn" action="#{threadVotesBean.downvote(thread)}" />
        </div>
    </ui:repeat>
</h:form>
```

```js
    // function called when DOM is ready (page fully loaded.)
    $(function(){

        //selecting form element.
        var $form = $('#threadsForm');

        // the form element injects an event on all elements with class 'voteBtn'.
        $form.on('click', '.voteBtn', function(event) {
            // select the element that triggered the click event
            var $clickedBtn = $(event.currentTarget); 

            // lookup for parent element with 'group' class and find inside it all children elements with class 'voteBtn' to remove 'active' class. 
            $clickedBtn.parent('.group').find('.voteBtn').removeClass('active');

            // then, back to the trigger element, just add 'active' class to it.
            $clickedBtn.addClass('active');
        });

    });
```

Do "ui:repeat" render any div or span? If yes, it will not work.

Comment: OP has jQuery at hands. And, I gather that only the button pair should be manipulated, and not all other buttons in the same document.